# How to generically compose monadic functions that return different monads?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads

From what I understand if you have many functions of the type `f: a -> m[b]` and as long as they all return values wrapped in `m` you should be able to chain them via `do/bind/flatMap`:

```
f: A -> M[B]
g: B -> M[C]
h: C -> M[D]
```

This is fairly straightforward to chain via `>>=` or `flatMap` (Scala).

How would one go about composing functions that differed in the monad "boxes" but the values *inside* were "chainable"?

```
f: A -> M[B]
g: B -> N[C]
h: C -> P[D]
```

I've never seen/read of this case and I understand that we can `lift` monads but that'll defeat the purpose IMO. Is this a limitation of the monadic construct? Can we even chain them? What's the canonical way to solve this problem?

Comment: Monads do not compose. So in the general sense, this is not possible. If you knew which specific monas you want to use, you may use specific monad transformers to combine those operations.

Comment: The idea is that you can not "unwrap" a value out of a monad (well at least not in general). You can see a monad as a "container", where your for example put a certain side-effect in safely.

Comment: If you did that, you would go from a `M[B]` to a `M[N[C]]` to a `M[N[P[D]]]`, which is pretty messy

Comment: Is it not possible to create a construct that allows one to achieve this? Could a combo of Arrow/Kleisli help solve this or is this not possible at all?

Comment: Monads combine/chain contexts not values inside these contexts. You can compose different monads but such a composition would be specific to the involved monads and their order. You can use monad transformers to get a more formal way of composing them. So yes, monads do not compose in general and this is a limitation of the concept and is actually one of the reasons for the existence of extensible effects with free/freer monads, tagless final etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez said, monads do not compose. If you have `M[A]`, `N[B]` and `O[C]` you cannot just take them and combine into... exactly into what?

You might want to combine them into something like `M[N[O[D]]]`. But there `flatMap` would only work on the outermost monad. If you make the computation go through all layers you would have to have a monad transformer for each layer except the outermost.

Could that combined type be generated out of the box? Also not because `M[N[O[D]]]` would not be the same as `O[N[M[D]]]` and there should be some way of deciding the order in deterministic way.

You could pass natural transformations into `Target[_]` from each of types, which would let you transform  `M[A]`, `N[B]` and `O[C]` into `Target[A]`, `Target[B]` and `Target[C]` and combine them as monad, but that is far from straightforward.

Then there were approaches where instead of using specific `M[_]`, `N[_]`, `O[_]`, you pass them as parameters, pass Target as parameter and somehow be able to add and effect to type and execute it - `Freer`, its optimized form `Eff` and algebraic effects are such a way of creating a type=level list of effects and adding and removing them (by interpreting/running one layer). As far as I can tell these attempts were successful in that they made it possible in general to do what they promised... but the mental overhead made them super non-practical and hard to understand for majority of people. Definitively, not straightforward. Also sometimes misleading, because they sometimes pretend that order in which we interpret effects doesn't matter while in fact it does.

Currently, if you need to stack effects you are more likely using tagless final to use one, composed effect everywhere, use MTL type classes to provide state/reader/writer/etc abilities next to monadic interface. And if you had to convert between effects you would have to pass natural transformations.

So to summarize, in general this problem is not solved and even now Haskell community searches for some new solutions. Even now there is a development on libraries like [Eff](https://github.com/hasura/eff) and [Polysemy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polysemy) which as far as I can tell are freer/eff monad but with build-in compiler support. For now at best you can decide on you aggregated effect upfront or defer the choice via TTFI and MTL. Just taking different monads and lumping them together... not possible without thinking and writing how.

Comment: I see. Perhaps an equivalent of `Target` _could_ be an `Either[L,R]` since almost always a monad can be transformed to this one where the `right` can hold the expected result and `left` the errors. That would imply making a “convention” of using `EitherT` which could atleast get the pipeline going. It _could_ be a potential solution without the need to have `n^2` transformers - between `M, N, O` in all directions.

Comment: I have a zero familiarity with `tagless final` - I had to google it to know what you were alluding to. Hence I can’t relate to that aspect of the answer and the insight gained. Seems time for further reading ;)

Comment: Well, it is a huge topic and answering it in-depth is equal to writing a long article. I once did it and it was _a loooong_ article, so forgive me of not wanting to do it again.